# BodyParser parse data instead of connect-multiparty in node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, multipart, body-parser

I am trying to upload file using connect-multiparty with reference of [connect-multiparty](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/node.js-example)
 below is my express.js config for that.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    //file upload configuration
    app.use(multipart({
            uploadDir: config.tmp
    }));
```

but when I upload file than it gives me request size if too long. I search for this and found that I need to set limit so I have also put limit parameter like below:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'}));
```

but after that I start getting Invalid json error. than I found that bodyParser could not parse multi-part data. but i don't know how can i use multipart middleware to parse multi-part data.

Comment: What is the scenario? You have a multipart request that contain json objects? Why are you using 2 parsers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [node-formidable module to handle multipart form data](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable):

```
var formidable = require('formidable');

app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      console.log(fields);
      console.log(files);
      res.send('done');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either **bodyParser** or **connect-multiparty** to parse request.

Both cannot be used at same time. You can parse json with connect-multiparty than why use bodyParser but bodyParser cannot parse multipart forms so we need to use other parsers like connect-multparty.

see this [link](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

Comment: after using only connect-multiparty now it stops parsing json data as well

Comment: @llesh Patel how are youaccessing your req paremeters ?

Comment: @llesh Patel see [link](https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty) it is accessing json object by req.body

Comment: I am not sure how can i use it to parse data. can you give me an example for that if you have?

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" in form is important

Answer (score 0):

index.html code

```
<html><body>
<div id="main-content">
    <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="text" name="FirstName" ><br>
             <input type="text" name="LastName" ><br>
            <input type="submit">
            </div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();

app.use("/",  express.static(__dirname + '/client/'));

app.post('/upload', multipartMiddleware, function(req, resp) {
    console.log(req);
  console.log(req.body);
  // don't forget to delete all req.files when done
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("App Started on PORT 3000");
});
```