# Empty req.files with connect-multiparty and body-parser

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, body-parser

I'm trying to **upload a file** with `connect-multiparty` on my api but I can't make it works.

Here my code (a sample, because my api have a lot of working routes):

```
var express             = require('express');
var bodyParser          = require('body-parser');
var multipart           = require('connect-multiparty');
var app                 = express();
var multipartMiddleware = multipart({ uploadDir: './imagesPath' });

// Define middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Support encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());                         // Support json encoded bodies

var router = express.Router();                      // Get an instance of the express Router

router.post('/testFileUpload', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body, req.files);

    // Some other code
});
```

When I try to upload a file both `req.body` and `req.files` are empty `{}`

I know `Body-Parser` doesn't support `multipart/form-data` anymore so I'm trying to find a way to use it with another package but with no success so far.

I've tried with `busboy`, `connect-busboy`, `multer`, `formidable`, `express-formidable`, `express-fileupload` but everytime `req.files` is `undefined`, so I kinda feel I've make some progress with `connect-multiparty` by having `req.files` empty.

I've seen some topics with similar problems like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014422/bodyparser-parse-data-instead-of-connect-multiparty-in-node-js), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914272/proper-way-to-use-connect-multiparty-with-express-js) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151459/empty-object-returned-for-uploaded-files-with-connect-multiparty) but unfortunatly none of those helped me.

In **client side** I'm using `Advanced REST Client` and `Postman`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

To whoever has this problem, I found removing the Content-Type headers on Postman with value "application/javascript" worked for me. I just hadn't noticed the whole time, while I tried different packages same as OP.

Answer (score 0):

put enctype="multipart/form-data" in your tag form on html